# Fetch all bestseller product with custom date range

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am working on a custom report for bestseller products, Following is a requirement,

1. Add Custom date range
2. Fetch all products max limit is 500

I am not able to set custom date range & limit, Following is a sample external script code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory');
$collection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection');
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$collection->setPeriod('year');
```

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory as BestSellersCollectionFactory;



public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    DateTime $dateTime,
    BestSellersCollectionFactory $bestSellersCollectionFactory
) {
    
    $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
    $this->_bestSellersCollectionFactory = $bestSellersCollectionFactory;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}
/**
 * get collection of best-seller products
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $productIds = [];

    $currentTime = $this->dateTime->date();
    $bestSellers = $this->_bestSellersCollectionFactory->create()
        ->setPeriod('month');
    foreach ($bestSellers as $product) {
        $productIds[] = $product->getProductId();
    }
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addIdFilter($productIds);
    $collection->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('from_date', ['lteq' => $currentTime])
    ->addFieldToFilter('to_date', ['gteq' => $currentTime])
    ->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC')
        ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId())->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount());
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Hello Waqar,
Following is wrong, i have to set custom date range here from_date and to_date
$bestSellers = $this->_bestSellersCollectionFactory->create() ->setPeriod('month');